# Should I wrap the recursive step in an "else"?

Tags: c#, coding-style, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [else or return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848663/else-or-return)

Consider a typical recursive function:

```
public int Fact(n) 
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return n * Fact(n-1);
    }
}
```

What is there a difference between writing it that way and this way?:

```
public int Fact(n) 
{
    if (n < 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return n * Fact(n-1);
}
```

I prefer latter, specially when the recursive step consists of many lines of code. I don't want to add unnecessary indentation.

Is there a practical difference or is this just a stylistic preference?

Comment: What are all of the code labels for? (And I don't think there's any difference other than readability.)

Comment: @JaredFarrish Which ones is more readable in your opinion?

Comment: I think the second form is potentially more easily mistyped than the first (hence, the first is more expressive visually). I don't have a preference other than that. I'm not a big fan of omitting using curly braces in a language like PHP.

Comment: Technically, you could do `return (n < 2 ? 1 : n * fact(n-1))`, but that would impact readability even more. But it's all on one line.

Comment: @pessimopoppotamus - Truly, you should think through your question all the way before posting it. You first asked about a number of languages, than tagged it `python` then `c#` and finally you chase me for clarification to an answer I deleted in a totally unrelated question... I understand you did not mean any harm and you were in good faith, yet for me it was just a waste of my time. :(

Comment: Can you stop hopping languages, this makes it hard for folks to answer and for their answers to remain valid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+if+else

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a matter of style. Usually I do not use *else* blocks when the end of the *then* block returns.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a difference. If the "If statement" is true it will go to the 1st return statement. If it is not true then the program will go to the 2nd return statement.

Comment: There is no such difference between them. If you were to include `else`, the second return statement would be executed, if the specified condition is false which is so true, if you were to exclude `else`.

Answer (score 2):

The functions are completely equivalent. It's a matter of personal preference, but some IDEs might complain about the first version, since clearly the `else` is unnecessary . But some could argue that the first version is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

There is no practical difference between them. Its depends upon the situations and the environment in which you're living in.

Comment: what does "environment in which you're living in" goto do with programming? :P just curious

Comment: @footy:) I meant practical programming environment and situation which is going on.

Comment: oh ok.... does make sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The fact is that in recursive function call you will return a specific value or you return a return of same function call.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** It seems this answer is generating some confusion. I first wrote it, then deleted it, but then I still got messages and inquiries on its content. So here it is online again.

The problem is that the question was edited a number of times radically changing its meaning: when I first answered it, it was tagged **python** and had python code in it. By the time I got the first upvote, the question was tagged **C++** and people begun commenting on the "compiler optimisations options".

So: here it goes again the original answer but keep in mind **it refers to python**.

---

> Is there a practical difference or is this just a stylistic preference?

Contrarily to common belief, there is a practical difference too: performance! Whether the difference is of any significance in your application that depends... but if your code is called recursively or in a loop:

```
>>> T(lambda : fact1(1)).repeat(number=10000000)
[2.5754408836364746, 2.5710129737854004, 2.5678811073303223]
>>> T(lambda : fact2(1)).repeat(number=10000000)
[2.8432059288024902, 2.834425926208496, 2.8364310264587402]
```

where `fact1` is defined as the with-else function, and `fact2` is the one without.

HTH!

Comment: This is surprising. Why would the one without the else be slower?

Comment: @pessimopoppotamus I'm no expert on the matter. My **guess** (I'll be happy to be corrected if I am wrong) is that the difference is in the way they get compiled to bytecode: an `else` allow the interpreter to probably prune that branch of code automatically on the `if` clause, while in the case of an early return pruning that part is an action that requires some overhead. I shall repeat: mine is just a guess I might be wrong! :)

Comment: I think it just depends on the compiler optimization options and how its implemented and not a common thing.