# Why can a Python dict have multiple keys with the same hash?

Tags: python, hash, dictionary, set, equality

I am trying to understand the Python `hash` function under the hood. I created a custom class where all instances return the same hash value.

```
class C:
    def __hash__(self):
        return 42
```

I just assumed that only one instance of the above class can be in a `dict` at any time, but in fact a `dict` can have multiple elements with the same hash.

```
c, d = C(), C()
x = {c: 'c', d: 'd'}
print(x)
# {<__main__.C object at 0x7f0824087b80>: 'c', <__main__.C object at 0x7f0823ae2d60>: 'd'}
# note that the dict has 2 elements
```

I experimented a little more and found that if I override the `__eq__` method such that all the instances of the class compare equal, then the `dict` only allows one instance.

```
class D:
    def __hash__(self):
        return 42
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

p, q = D(), D()
y = {p: 'p', q: 'q'}
print(y)
# {<__main__.D object at 0x7f0823a9af40>: 'q'}
# note that the dict only has 1 element
```

So I am curious to know how a `dict` can have multiple elements with the same hash.

Comment: As you discovered yourself, sets and dicts can contain multiple objects with equal hashes if the objects aren't equal themselves. What are you asking? How has tables work? That's a quite general question with lots of existing material...

Comment: @delnan I was thinking more about about this after I posted the question; that this behavior cannot be restricted to Python. And you're right. I guess I should delve deeper into general Hash table literature. Thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For a detailed description of how Python's hashing works see my answer to [Why is early return slower than else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271139)

Basically it uses the hash to pick a slot in the table. If there is a value in the slot and the hash matches, it compares the items to see if they are equal.

If the hash matches but the items aren't equal, then it tries another slot. There's a formula to pick this (which I describe in the referenced answer), and it gradually pulls in unused parts of the hash value; but once it has used them all up, it will eventually work its way through all slots in the hash table. That guarantees eventually we either find a matching item or an empty slot. When the search finds an empty slot, it inserts the value or gives up (depending whether we are adding or getting a value).

The important thing to note is that there are no lists or buckets: there is just a hash table with a particular number of slots, and each hash is used to generate a sequence of candidate slots.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction about Hash table implementation. I've read much more than I ever wanted to about hash tables and I explained my findings in a separate answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9022664/553995

Comment: But what about comparing values? If the values are the same, does it just skip that operation or create a new object in memory and update the reference in the hashtable? What about if the values differ? Does it just create a new object in memory and change the reference to the new object in the hashtable?

Answer (score 159):

Here is everything about Python dicts that I was able to put together (probably more than anyone would like to know; but the answer is comprehensive). A shout out to [Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107660/duncan) for pointing out that Python dicts use slots and leading me down this rabbit hole.

- Python dictionaries are implemented as **hash tables**.
- Hash tables must allow for **hash collisions** i.e. even if two keys have same hash value, the implementation of the table must have a strategy to insert and retrieve the key and value pairs unambiguously.
- Python dict uses **open addressing** to resolve hash collisions (explained below) (see [dictobject.c:296-297](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l296)).
- Python hash table is just a continguous block of memory (sort of like an array, so you can do `O(1)` lookup by index).
- **Each slot in the table can store one and only one entry.** This is important
- Each **entry** in the table actually a combination of the three values - . This is implemented as a C struct (see [dictobject.h:51-56](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Include/dictobject.h#l51))
- The figure below is a logical representation of a python hash table. In the figure below, 0, 1, ..., i, ... on the left are indices of the **slots** in the hash table (they are just for illustrative purposes and are not stored along with the table obviously!).

  ```
  # Logical model of Python Hash table
  -+-----------------+
  0| <hash|key|value>|
  -+-----------------+
  1|      ...        |
  -+-----------------+
  .|      ...        |
  -+-----------------+
  i|      ...        |
  -+-----------------+
  .|      ...        |
  -+-----------------+
  n|      ...        |
  -+-----------------+
  ```
- When a new dict is initialized it starts with 8 *slots*. (see [dictobject.h:49](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Include/dictobject.h#l49))
- When adding entries to the table, we start with some slot, `i` that is based on the hash of the key. CPython uses initial `i = hash(key) & mask`. Where `mask = PyDictMINSIZE - 1`, but that's not really important). Just note that the initial slot, i, that is checked depends on the *hash* of the key.
- If that slot is empty, the entry is added to the slot (by entry, I mean, `<hash|key|value>`). But what if that slot is occupied!? Most likely because another entry has the same hash (hash collision!)
- If the slot is occupied, CPython (and even PyPy) compares the **the hash AND the key** (by compare I mean `==` comparison not the `is` comparison)  of the entry in the slot against the key of the current entry to be inserted ([dictobject.c:337](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l337),[344-345](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l344)). If *both* match, then it thinks the entry already exists, gives up and moves on to the next entry to be inserted. If either hash or the key don't match, it starts **probing**.
- Probing just means it searches the slots by slot to find an empty slot. Technically we could just go one by one, i+1, i+2, ... and use the first available one (that's linear probing). But for reasons explained beautifully in the comments (see [dictobject.c:33-126](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l33)), CPython uses **random probing**. In random probing, the next slot is picked in a pseudo random order. The entry is added to the first empty slot. For this discussion, the actual algorithm used to pick the next slot is not really important (see [dictobject.c:33-126](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Objects/dictobject.c#l33) for the algorithm for probing). What is important is that the slots are probed until first empty slot is found.
- The same thing happens for lookups, just starts with the initial slot i (where i depends on the hash of the key). If the hash and the key both don't match the entry in the slot, it starts probing, until it finds a slot with a match. If all slots are exhausted, it reports a fail.
- BTW, the dict will be resized if it is two-thirds full. This avoids slowing down lookups. (see [dictobject.h:64-65](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/52f68c95e025/Include/dictobject.h#l64))

There you go! The Python implementation of dict checks for both hash equality of two keys and the normal equality (`==`) of the keys when inserting items. So in summary, if there are two keys, `a` and `b` and `hash(a)==hash(b)`, but `a!=b`, then both can exist harmoniously in a Python dict. But if `hash(a)==hash(b)` **and** `a==b`, then they cannot both be in the same dict.

Because we have to probe after every hash collision, one side effect of too many hash collisions is that the lookups and insertions will become very slow (as Duncan points out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9010277/553995)).

I guess the short answer to my question is, "Because that's how it's implemented in the source code ;)"

While this is good to know (for geek points?), I am not sure how it can be used in real life. Because unless you are trying to explicitly break something, why would two objects that are not equal, have same hash?

Comment: This explains how filling up the dictionary works. But what if there's a hash collision during retrieval of a key_value pair. Say we have 2 objects A and B, both of which hash to 4. So first A is assigned slot 4 and then B is assigned slot through random probing. What happens when I want to retrieve B. B hashes to 4, so python first checks slot 4, but the key doesn't match so it can't return A. Because B's slot was assigned by random probing, how is B returned again in O(1) time?

Comment: @Bolt64 the random probing isn't really random. For the same key values it always follows the same sequence of probes so it will eventually find B. Dictionaries aren't guaranteed to be O(1), if you get a lot of collisions they can take longer. With older versions of Python it is easy to construct a series of keys that will collide and in that case dictionary lookups become O(n). This is a possible vector for DoS attacks so newer Python versions modify the hashing to make it harder to do this deliberately.

Comment: @Duncan what if A is deleted and then we perform a lookup on B ?  I guess you don't actually delete entries but mark them as deleted ? That would mean that the dicts are not suitable for continuous inserts and deletes....

Comment: @gen-y-s yes deleted and unused are handled differently for lookup. Unused stops the search for a match but deleted doesn't. On insert either deleted or unused are treated as empty slots that can be used. Continuous inserts and deletes are fine. When the number of unused (not deleted) slots drops too low the hash table will be rebuilt in the same way as if it had grown too large for the current table.

Comment: This is not a very good answer on the collision point which Duncan tried to remedy. It's an especially poor answer to reference for implementation from your question. The thing that's prime to understanding this is that if there a collision Python tries again using a formula to calculate the next offset in the hash table. On retrieval if the key isn't the same, it uses that same formula to look up the next offset. There is nothing random about it.

Comment: How exactly does the resizing work ?

Answer (score 20):

**Edit**: the answer below is one of possible ways to deal with hash collisions, it is however **not** how Python does it. Python's wiki referenced below is also incorrect. The best source given by @Duncan below is the implementation itself: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c I apologize for the mix-up.

---

It stores a list (or bucket) of elements at the hash then iterates through that list until it finds the actual key in that list. A picture says more than a thousand words:

[image: Hash table]

Here you see `John Smith` and `Sandra Dee` both hash to `152`. Bucket `152` contains both of them. When looking up `Sandra Dee` it first finds the list in bucket `152`, then loops through that list until `Sandra Dee` is found and returns `521-6955`.

**The following is wrong it's only here for context:** On [Python's wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys) you can find (pseudo?) code how Python performs the lookup.

There's actually several possible solutions to this problem, check out the wikipedia article for a nice overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and especially for the link to Python wiki entry with the pseudo code!

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is just plain wrong (so is the wiki article). Python does not store a list or bucket of elements at the hash: it stores precisely one object in each slot of the hash table. If the slot that it first tries to use is occupied then it picks another slot (pulling in unused parts of the hash as long as possible) and then another and another. Since no hash table is ever more than one third full it must eventually find an available slot.

Comment: @Duncan, Python's wiki says it is implemented this way. I'd be happy to find at a better source. The wikipedia.org page definitely isn't wrong, it's just one of possible solutions as stated.

Comment: @Duncan Can you please explain ... pulling in unused parts of the hash as long as possible? *All* the hashes in my case evaluate to 42. Thanks!

Comment: @PraveenGollakota Follow the link in my answer, that explains in gory detail how the hash is used. For a hash of 42 and a table with 8 slots initially only the lowest 3 bits are used to find slot number 2 but if that slot is already used the remaining bits come into play. If two values have exactly the same hash then the first goes in the first slot tried and the second gets the next slot. If there are 1000 values with identical hashes then we end up trying 1000 slots before we find the value and the dictionary lookup gets very *very* slow!

Comment: @RobWouters The wikipedia page is generic, the Python wiki page you referenced is the one that is wrong. A better source is http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c (even if you don't read C read the long comment at the start).

Comment: @Duncan, thank you for the link. I stand corrected. What is the way to set this straight? In any case I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @RobWouters I've read much more than I've ever wanted to know about Python hash tables. I the light of the new found knowledge, I realized while your answer applies generically to hash tables, Duncan's answer is more relevant to the original question. Sorry, I've to unaccept your answer and accept Duncan's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hash tables, in general have to allow for hash collisions! You will get unlucky and two things will eventually hash to the same thing. Underneath, there is a set of objects in a list of items that has that same hash key. Usually, there is only one thing in that list, but in this case, it'll keep stacking them into the same one. The only way it knows they are different is through the equals operator.

When this happens, your performance will degrade over time, which is why you want your hash function to be as "random as possible".

Answer (score 3):

In the thread I did not see what exactly python does with instances of a user-defined classes when we put it into a dictionary as a keys. Let's read some documentation: it declares that only hashable objects can be used as a keys. Hashable are all immutable built-in classes and all user-defined classes.

> User-defined classes have __cmp__() and
>   __hash__() methods by default;  with them, all objects
>   compare unequal (except with themselves) and
>   x.__hash__()  returns a result derived from id(x).

So if you have a constantly __hash__ in your class, but not providing any __cmp__ or __eq__ method, then all your instances are unequal for the dictionary.
In the other hand, if you providing any __cmp__ or __eq__ method, but not providing __hash__, your instances are still unequal in terms of dictionary.

```
class A(object):
    def __hash__(self):
        return 42


class B(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True


class C(A, B):
    pass


dict_a = {A(): 1, A(): 2, A(): 3}
dict_b = {B(): 1, B(): 2, B(): 3}
dict_c = {C(): 1, C(): 2, C(): 3}

print(dict_a)
print(dict_b)
print(dict_c)
```

Output

```
{<__main__.A object at 0x7f9672f04850>: 1, <__main__.A object at 0x7f9672f04910>: 3, <__main__.A object at 0x7f9672f048d0>: 2}
{<__main__.B object at 0x7f9672f04990>: 2, <__main__.B object at 0x7f9672f04950>: 1, <__main__.B object at 0x7f9672f049d0>: 3}
{<__main__.C object at 0x7f9672f04a10>: 3}
```