# Non-deterministic dictionary creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following `testcase_dict.py` script:

```
print([{x: 'hello', 'x': 'y'} for x in [1, 2]])
```

I run this script, and every 15 times, 2-4 times it gives me distincted results:

```
 $ for i in $(seq 15); do python testcase_dict.py; done
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {'x': 'y', 2: 'hello'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{'x': 'y', 1: 'hello'}, {'x': 'y', 2: 'hello'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {'x': 'y', 2: 'hello'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {'x': 'y', 2: 'hello'}]
[{'x': 'y', 1: 'hello'}, {'x': 'y', 2: 'hello'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
[{1: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}, {2: 'hello', 'x': 'y'}]
```

Why this happens and how can I prevent it. This may be a reason of some raise conditions which are strongly unwelcome.

My Python version is 3.5.2.

My question DOES NOT regard specific order, just deterministic one.

Comment: I realize dictionaries are not ordered and I do not need `OrderedDict`. I would like to have only deterministic order. There is nothing random here.

Comment: Then use a list of tuples?

Comment: @pt12lol you might be interested in the information in the answers for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010222/how-can-python-dict-have-multiple-keys-with-same-hash

Comment: @pt12lol> dicts are not ordered. This means the have NO ORDER. Therefore they cannot have a deterministic order. If you want to **display** them in a specific order, you must order the keys by yourself.

Comment: @spectras ok, but still iteration through keys is not deterministic.

Comment: @pt12lol> indeed it's not. It's not advertised as such either. Iterate on `sorted(mydict.keys())` if you want it to be consistent. The only guarantee is that iterating a dictionnary will yield entries in the same order if you do it several times without modifying it. This applies only to a single dictionnary object, not across dictionnaries, even if they have the same content.

Answer (score 2):

`dict` is not  ordered, and can display arbitrary ordering.... you should read about `collections.OrderedDict`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: `dict`s are ordered from 3.6 on (unofficially in some versions of 3.5, I think)

Comment: @hop which is not to be relied on, as stressed many times by core devs since it is an implementation detail and not a language feature. The only thing that *can* be relied on in 3.6 in this regard is the presevredorder of class attributes and functions kwargs.

Comment: @a_guest: sounds like you are confusing "sorted" and "ordered". in principle one and the same `dict` (used to be) is free to return keys in an ordered whenever you call `.keys()` or similar. that they don't is just an implementation detail. also, since recreating the "same key-value pairs" might not be possible, the distinction is moot.

Comment: @DeepSpace: which you can read in my answer. "dict is not ordered" is simply a false statement.

Answer (score 0):

Although dictionaries are deterministically ordered in Python from version 3.6 on (but not before), you should not rely on that fact.

If you need a dictionary like type that guarantees order, use `collections.OrderedDict` or sort the keys before iterating over them.

"Ordered" in both cases means: [remembers the order entries were added](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

Comment: I realize dictionaries are not ordered and I do not need OrderedDict. I would like to have only deterministic order. There is nothing random in my script.

Comment: @pt12lol: there, fixed it for you.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Because it is not an answer to my question at all.

Comment: @pt12lol> your question is meaningless. Something that is unordered, that is which has no order cannot have a deterministic order.

Comment: @spectras: thanks! I was not sure I was in the correct movie there for a minute.

Comment: @spectras nope, I would suppose it can be ordered based on hashes and I am completely surprised it changes through specific calls history.