# Python Object as Dict Key using __hash__ for access

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Take this super simple class:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, iden):
        self.iden = iden
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.iden)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.iden)
```

The goal is to create instances of the class to use as dict keys.  If `__repr__` is omitted, the keys are the standard object address.  With `__repr__` a printable representation might be:

```
f = Foo(1)
g = Foo(2)
d = {f:'a', g:'b'}
print(d)
>>> {1:'a', 2:'b'}
```

When attempting to access the dict by key though, it does not appear to be immediately obvious how to utilize the `__repr__` (or `__str__` for that matter) representation as the key.

```
print(d[1]) 
>>> KeyError
```

Comment: How to utilize `__str__`/`__repr__` to do *what*, exactly? An object's place in a `dict` (or `set`) is based only on its hash. `__repr__` only affects how an object _appears_, not how you can reference it.

Comment: The answer is no. As I said, the repr is only relevant to how the object is _displayed_, not how you can reference it.

Comment: @glibdud The above fails using `__hash__` as well.  `hash(1) == 1`, but `d[1]` fails with a key error.

Comment: Good point. It appears that something else (possibly type?) is taken into account in addition to hash. I'll see if I can find a reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing's first: `__repr__()` is a red herring. It only affects how the object is displayed. It has nothing to do with what you're trying to do.

If you want to have two separate objects refer to the same slot in a dict, you need two things ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010222/how-can-python-dict-have-multiple-keys-with-same-hash)):

- The objects must have the same hash (`hash(obj1) == hash(obj2)`).
- The objects must compare equal (`obj1 == obj2`).

Your above implementation does the former, but not the latter. You need to add an `__eq__()` method (which is actually required by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) when you define `__hash__()`, anyway).

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, iden):
        self.iden = iden
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.iden)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.iden == other
```

```
>>> d = {Foo(1) : 'a'}
>>> d[1]
'a'
```